# Meaning of the text_index parameter in the Concept Insights annotateText call?

Tags: ibm-watson, concept-insights

The example [/annotateText](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/swagger.html?url=/listings/concept-insights-v2.json#!/graphs/annotateText) Concept Insights call provides the following example output:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -d 'IBM announces new Watson services.' 

'https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/concept-insights/api/v2/graphs/wikipedia/en-20120601/annotate_text'

{
  "annotations": [
    {
      "concept": {
        "id": "/graphs/wikipedia/en-20120601/concepts/Watson_(computer)",
        "label": "Watson (computer)"
      },
      "score": 0.99832845,
      "text_index": [
        18,
        24
      ]
    },
    {
      "concept": {
        "id": "/graphs/wikipedia/en-20120601/concepts/IBM",
        "label": "IBM"
      },
      "score": 0.9980473,
      "text_index": [
        0,
        3
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the meaning of the `text_index` parameter that is being returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text_index` tells you the start and end position where the identified concept is.

In your example, the concept `IBM_Watson` was identified in the snippet `IBM announces new Watson`.